# Connecting flights in johannesburg?

Tags: short-connections, johannesburg

I am flying from London to Maun botswana and changing in johannesburg. I have bought two seperate tickets and have a 2 hour stop over.

I am only taking hand luggage but will i need to exit customs and re-check in for my next flight? Or can I walk straight through to international flights? Is there somewhere to check in?

Comment: It seems there are flights to Maun leaving from both terminal A (international) and terminal B (domestic). What airline/flights are you on?

Comment: That's a very risky schedule. If your flight to Johannesburg is delayed, you'll miss your connection. Because you're traveling on separate tickets, it's your responsibility to get to the airport on time for your flight to Botswana, so the airline there is within its rights to say, "You missed your flight. Tough luck." (With connections on the same ticket, the airline is responsible for making sure you make your connection and, if they don't, they must put you on a later flight.)